# Does cloud front supports RTMP for live streaming?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, rtmp, live-streaming

We are planning for live streaming (both sides- class room scenario) currently using wowza media server, ec2 and AWS cloudfront. We could successfully do http streaming and integrated AWS cloudfront however, in case of RTMP streaming we are not sure how to go about it as it cache is important it will determine our cost and bandwidth usage?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront supports RTMP. Here's the documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-rtmp.html

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront only supports on demand RTMP streaming[1].  However, you can do live HTTP streaming, as you mentioned, using Wowza and CloudFront[2].  Why does the live stream have to be RTMP to your clients?

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-rtmp.html
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/live-streaming-wowza.html

Comment: the problem with http streaming is the delay, it has a lot more delay than RTMP.